# Are there semantically well-defined purely ternary+ relations?

Tags: semantics

By purely ternary+, I mean a relation that cannot be expressed using binary ones. For example, "B is closer to A than to C" is ternary, but can be expressed using only a binary relation.

B is closer to A than to C iff f(B, A) < f(B, C), for some function f and order relation <.

And by semantically well-defined I mean that it's not a random set of triplets.

The reason why I am asking here instead of on the math stackexchange is due to an interest in "grammatical reasoning" games, where the player is presented with one or many propositions involving relations and they must answer as quickly as possible.

Usually these relations pertain to membership/containment and relative size/position. I am looking for something that is a bit more involved, and that can't necessarily be divided into steps.

Comment: What about "Z is the sum of X and Y if X + Y = Z"? There's no way I can see to express that without information about all three numbers.

Comment: @Draconis so, this is not about evaluation per se, but about whether the relation itself cannot be broken down to simpler, binary ones. The one that you propose has triplets that verify =(+(X, Y), Z), where both + and = are binary.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked this on Linguistics and not Math, you may be interested in (neo-)Davidsonian event semantics. Before Davidson, a sentence like *John hit Mary* might be formalized as "hit(John, Mary)". This approach runs into trouble with adjuncts. For example, we might still say that *John hit Mary with a stick* can be formalized as "hit(John, Mary, stick)", even though this means that *hit* is both binary and ternary. To say that *John hit Mary on Tuesday* can be formalized as "hit(John, Mary, Tuesday)" is really pushing it.

What Davidson came up with is that there is an *event* argument that can be used to link adjuncts. Thus *John hit Mary with a stick on Tuesday* would be formalized as "∃*e* : hit(*e*, John, Mary) & with(*e*, stick) & on(*e*, Tuesday)". Here, *e* is the event argument. You can read this as: "there is an event which is a hitting event between John and Mary, happened with a stick, and happened on Tuesday".

Parsons suggested that all relations can be reduced to binary ones with an event: "∃*e* : hit(*e*) & Agent(*e*, John) & Patient(*e*, Mary) & Instrument(*e*, stick) & On(*e*, Tuesday)". Read as: "there is an event which is a hitting event, of which John is the Agent, Mary is the Patient, which happened with a stick as Instrument, and happened on Tuesday".

So in this way you can reduce seemingly ternary relations (e.g., *X gave Y to Z*) to binary ones, and this is indeed commonly done.

Finally:

> B is between A and C is iff f(B, A) < f(B, C), for some function f and order relation <.

Maybe I'm missing something, but this looks like an odd definition to me. I would probably say "f(A) ≤ f(B) and f(B) ≤ f(C)". With your definition, it seems like you would need odd f and < to say that B=10 is between A=1 and C=11.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry about the between example. This was a discussion that I was having with some people, and the f(B, A) < f(B, C) was for a different relation that preceded "between" in the discussion. I confused them...

Comment: The introduction of the event as a proxy is pretty clever, but I guess I am looking for relations that one doesn't have to implicate extra objects in order to reduce them to binary ones.

Comment: @AnotherSherlock the example =(+(X,Y),Z) that you gave on the question does the same though: there is a p such that +(X,Y)=p and Z=p. Similarly you can reformulate a Neo-Davidsonian analysis with an operator same-event: same-event(hit, same-event(Agent(John), same-event(Patient(Mary)))). So I'm not sure if the distinction you're making really amounts to anything. Maybe you could consider editing your question with some more explanation why you are asking linguists as opposed to mathematicians, that might help clarify what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post.

Comment: @AnotherSherlock I’m afraid I’m not familiar with the games you’re referring to. Today I realized that another argument can be made based on Chomsky’s notion of merge: if all language has is binary merge, then all relations have to be reducible to binary relations.